# Bootstrap 3, Opencart 1.5.6.4 and Cart module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, opencart, cart

Ok. I've changed smth and now it works ALMOST fine. Just one problem left.
Cart link in header (div with id **cart-total**) is not anymore in div with id **cart**. So when I delete product in cart modal, link in header is not updated, like it still has product.

Here is the new code `module/cart.tpl`

```html
<div class="heading">
    <?php echo $heading_title; ?> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart"><span id="cart-total"> <?php echo $text_items; ?></span></a>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cartLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="content modal-content text-left">
            <?php if ($products || $vouchers) { ?>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="cartLabel"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-hover mini-cart-info">
                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="image">
                            <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
                            </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
                            <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
                            - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?> <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small><br />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if ($product['recurring']): ?>
                            - <small><?php echo $text_payment_profile ?> <?php echo $product['profile']; ?></small><br />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="quantity">x&nbsp;<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
                        <td class="total"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
                        <td class="remove"><a alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' : $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');" /><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="image"></td>
                        <td class="name"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
                        <td class="quantity">x&nbsp;1</td>
                        <td class="total"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
                        <td class="remove"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/remove-small.png" alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $voucher['key']; ?>' : $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $voucher['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
                <div class="mini-cart-total">
                    <?php $i = count($totals); $i-- ; ?>
                    <?php echo $totals[$i]['title']; ?>: <?php echo $totals[$i]['text']; ?>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer checkout">
                <a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a> | <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="cartLabel"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body empty">
                <?php echo $text_empty; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is code from `common.js`

```js
/* Ajax Cart */
$('.heading a').live('click', function() {
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
});

function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

I wrapped all code in `cart.tpl` with `<div id="cart-container">`
1. I've changed `onClick` from:

```
<a alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' : $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');" />
<?php echo $button_remove; ?>
</a>
```

to:

```
<a alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' : $('#cart-container').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');" />
    <?php echo $button_remove; ?>
</a>
```

and it works like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5o0x44z8mqytw4/1st.png 2. I've changed modified `onClick` again from:

```
<a alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' : $('#cart-container').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');" />
    <?php echo $button_remove; ?>
</a>
```

to:

```
<a alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="(getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' : $('#cart-container').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart-container > *');" />
    <?php echo $button_remove; ?>
</a>
```

and it works like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uc6anoyo3yn8cfu/2nd.png

Answer (score 0):

Replace this js in `common.js` file and then check it.

```js
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert-success, .alert-warning, .alert-attention, .alert-info, .alert-danger').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'
                 + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button></div>');

                $('.alert-success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello @HarnishDesign , thank you for answer. Unfortunately it didn't help. And... sorry, isn't your code same as below? Maybe I'm not very attentive, but it looks like you accidentally paste this code instead of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with JS and not at all with *adding a product to the cart* (the JS code you have pasted here from `common.js`) - you yourself described the problem is *when I delete the product*.

Therefore you have to look at completely different place and that is (I formatted it little bit for better readability, you should do the same in your template):

```html
<td class="remove">
    <a alt="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="
        (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') 
            ? location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' 
            : $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');" /><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a>
</td>
```

Now the problem itself lies in this piece of the JS code in `onclick` callback:

```js
$('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>' + ' #cart > *');
```

This code *re-loads* the contents of `$('#cart')` with whatever is returned from requested URL `index.php?route=module/cart&remove=<?php echo $product['key']; ?>`.

This means that within your HTML markup the `<div id="cart">` is replaced while the `div.heading` above containing `span#cart-total` is not touched at all.

The fix could be this one:

1. wrap the whole code in `module/cart.tpl` in an additional div with id e.g. `cart-container`
2. replace the selector in `$('#cart').load(...)` with `#cart-container`.

Comment: thank you for your time and help. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I wrapped all with `<div id=cart=container>`, replaced selector in `$('#cart').load(...)`, but no.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you have some error? It does absolutely nothing (nothing happens)? I do not see a reason why it shouldn't work. Could you update your actual template's code in your question?

Comment: Sorry, will try to explain